# Using Typekit with MAMP

Tags: html, css, fonts, mamp, typekit

I'm using MAMP as my local server, and Typekit for my web font service. However, I'm having a world of bother, trying to get the font to render. I've put a little video together, so you can see where I'm possibly going wrong.

[Workflow screencast](http://quick.as/8QW8sVa7)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, with a huge weight lifted off my shoulders.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely culprit would be that you provide `localhost` as the domain to TypeKit, but you're viewing the webpage directly from the filesystem (`file:///Users/samuelryan/Desktop/mysite/index.html`) rather than via `http://localhost/` which it is expecting.

Where is your MAMP Apache document root? Put your files there and use `http://localhost`. Then the domain will match up and your font should load.

Comment: I've added a screenshot so you can see my MAMP settings. I thought it'd be better than typing it. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/us4sd7zownrs6es/Screenshot.jpg)

Comment: I've done it! Persistence always pays off in the end. Thank you for your help Josh.

Comment: I got it to work by adding this in the Typekit's settings: `127.0.0.1,localhost:8888,localhost`. It's possible that you'll have to clear the cache.